# Ubuntu 21.04 freezes on zoom Screen share option

Tags: xorg, wayland, zoom-meeting

Today I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04. It uses Wayland by default, also I have disabled my nvidia card (just selected Integrated Graphics from nvidia-settings). When I installed and tried zoom client from the Ubuntu Software I was not able to share screen on Wayland. Then I logged off and switched to Xorg session and tried the same thing. This time the zoom client freezed when I started to share my screen. There was not such a problem on 20.04, and I guess this is not solely related to Wayland.

Is there any fix for it?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu has two upgrade paths that are fully QA-tested, from one release to the next, **or** from one LTS to the next LTS, so 20.04 was fully QA-tested to move to 20.10 (and 20.10 to 21.04), and 20.04 will be fully QA-tested when 22.04 is near ready. You've gone outside of the intended & thus fully tested upgrade paths.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04, I also faced same problem. You just need to do following steps.

- Restart your system
- There is gear icon (bottom right side) on login screen
- Which have two options. First one is **Ubuntu** which is Wayland by default and another one is **Ubuntu on Xorg**.
- You have to go for **Ubuntu on Xorg**

It works for me.

Comment: You saved my day, thx. One addition: Initially the gear icon wasn't there until I pressed Enter which made the password input box appear. Seems somewhat related: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/878

Comment: my system froze after using zoom for like 5 minutes, I hope it's temporary :(

Comment: Wayland is very slow in my laptop. We need to find a solution with wayland :)