# Not able to share screen in MS Teams (v 1.4.00.7556) on Ubuntu 21.04 Hirsute Hippo

Tags: screen, sharing, microsoft-teams

Not able to share screen in MS Teams (v 1.4.00.7556) on Ubuntu 21.04  Hirsute Hippo

Comment: you can also check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333961/ubuntu-21-04-freezes-on-zoom-screen-share-option/1334829#1334829 out.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use xorg instead of Wayland? If not: logout, switch to xorg (click the symbol in the lower right corner of your logon screen) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Run

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file
```

and add or uncomment these lines

```
WaylandEnable=false

AutomaticLoginEnable = true

AutomaticLogin = user1
```